# Use local files and qrc

Tags: javascript, qt, qml, qt-quick

I have all my QML files provided by QRC. I want one js file to be a local file. I create a `data.js` file

```
.pragma library
var data = "some data"
```

The call

```
import "data.js" as Data
```

fails, since QML looks for the file in `qrc:/` and the file is stored locally.

Can I use the local file from QML without dropping QRC for the rest of the files?

Comment: Have you tried an absolute path? I'm not sure if even that will work. I'm pretty sure that imports are resolved from the same URL scheme that the component was loaded from, but I can't find the documentation that states that.